How to save a subplot in for loop?
Using this code to create and save a subplot automatically (in a for loop) is not working and throwing up an error I don't understand:
clear
clc
close all

%----------------------------
x1 = 1:0.01:3;
r = -1 + (1+1)*rand(1,201);
x1 = x1 + r;

y1 = 1:0.01:3;
r = -1 + (1+1)*rand(1,201);
y1 = y1 + r;

z1 = [1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9];

LC = 0

for nn = 1:10
    LC = LC+1
figure()
subplot(2,1,1)
scatter(x1,y1)
legend('Data')
subplot(2,1,2)
xvalues_HM = {'True label 1','True label 2','True label 3'};
yvalues_HM = {'Mdl label 3','Mdl label 2','Mdl label 1'};
h = heatmap(xvalues_HM,yvalues_HM,z1);

txtsave = [num2str(LC)];     
saveas(gcf,[ txtsave '.png']);
close all

end

I get this error message:
Error using alternatePrintPath
Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in alternatePrintPath

Error in print (line 83)
pj = alternatePrintPath(pj);

Error in saveas (line 181)
        print( h, name, ['-d' dev{i}] )

Error in script (line 396)
        saveas(gcf,[ txtsave '.png']);

Which makes no sense - what array is it concatenating? This code works when I ask it to save a figure (i.e. not a subplot).
Issue seen using MATLAB R2020a.

Thankyou for editing your question with a minimal example, but I'm not sure it's reproducible, because it doesn't produce that error. I've just tested this on 2020b and just get 10 images saved with no error. Are you certain that the code you've pasted above reproduces your error if you copy/paste it into a new script verbatim? If you do then it's likely one or more of the dependent functions is being shadowed on your path and giving unexpected results, try running from a brand new MATLAB instance with nothing on your path

Yes, I am certain this code does not work on MATLAB 2020a. I have confirmed this by copying it back from the post into matlab. Short of posting a screen recording idk what to show! Can you show one of the figures the code produces just so I know what output it's giving?

I'd be very hesitant to blame the MATLAB version, given Luis tested this on 18b and 24a and I've tested it on 20b, and there's no complex functions being called here, it definitely feels like something is messed up on your path or installation or otherwise. Here is my output from your test: https://i.sstatic.net/fzDax7K6.png

Apparently you are not the first to have had this problem, see a similar question on Matlab Answers. The answer there suggests that this is a bug introduced by heatmaps in a small number of matlab version (from 2019b to 2020a). Version 2020b seem to have fixed the problem (as also seen on this other SO question.

@Hoki good find, that looks like a direct duplicate of this Q although we can't mark it as such because there's no answer on that one either. Consider writing an answer on either so the other can be marked as duplicate to improve discoverability in future. I retract my scepticism about blaming the MATLAB version! I've added the OP's MATLAB ver to the body of the question to elevate its importance

I have also stumbled across a work around, as posted.

Removing the legend of the first figure now produces the desired subplot, albeit with unlabelled data.
As Hoki has linked to, this appears to be a bug with heatmaps around releases R2019b/R2020a.

So it appears the problem is with the legend rather than the heatmap object. Can you confirm that you still have the heatmap on your figure (only took out the legend)?

@Hoki, yes I can produce the heatmap and the figure, only when I comment out the line
legend('Data')

For completeness, it's worth noting I can manually save the figure with the legend.
